# why is System.lineSeparator() deprecated?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

[The screenshot of my intelliJ IDE as I could not post a picture directly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KDOh2.png)
(by the way am using jdk 10)
For some reason I need to output a String based on input and there might be new lines in the String. To make the program working on different platform I use a variable to store System.lineSeparator() and insert it when needed. But then I realized that intelliJ shows that it is deprecated. So my question is, why is this function deprecated? Is it a bad practice using line separators? What is the better way of doing this?

```
final String NEW_LINE = System.lineSeparator();
String output = "Line one" + NEW_LINE + "Line two";
WriteToFile(output);
```

update: the picture shows the warning in my intelliJ IDE. The problem might be caused by my configuration. According to answers below(thank you all for answering btw), maybe I should ask "Is it" before "why" next time.

Comment: I do not see it deprecated in [Java 9 API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#lineSeparator--) neither in my eclipse. Does deprecation has some kind of message?

Comment: `System.lineSeparator()` is not deprecated in any version of java starting in 7 where it was added and going to 10 right now.

Comment: Maybe IDE dependent? I use java plugin for VSCode and it does not show any warning.

Comment: Maybe because it's equivalent to `System.getProperty("line.separator")`? Would this one be better practice?

Comment: IntelliJ doesn't show it is deprecated when I use it. The [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#lineSeparator--) doesn't say it is deprecated. Cannot reproduce.

Comment: Watch out, you are pointing out a Java 9 documentation. As OP did not precisely point which JDK he is using, it is safe to assume he would use one of the most used, either 7 or 8. What JDK are you using, Jin. J ?

Comment: On 7, 8, 9 and 10 it is not deprecated. So it's not really important which documentation to point towards - they all say the exact same.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> why is this function deprecated?

This is the choice implemented by either a plugin, an add-on or a configuration setting in your IntelliJ (as some comments pointed out, their IntelliJ does not strike it as deprecated). As far as I can see, the only choice for deprecating this would be that it may bring a compatibility error. However, from the [Java System class documentation:](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html)

> **lineSeparator**
>
> *public static String lineSeparator()*
>
> Returns the system-dependent line separator string. It always returns the same value - the initial value of the system property line.separator.
>
> On UNIX systems, it returns "\n"; on Microsoft Windows systems it returns "\r\n".

There is no indication about deprecation of the `System.lineSeparator()`, as far as the version it was implemented ([Java 7](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/)) and up until the last version available ([Java 10](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/overview-summary.html)). If it really burns your mind, you may want to [ask the community directly](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/requests/new).

---

> Is it a bad practice using line separators?

Not at all (I may be wrong, as far as my knowledge goes), especially since you are using a line separator which is compatible with any system you are running your code on (theorically).

---

> What is the better way of doing this?

I don't have any better advice about your choice on design regarding this piece of code. It seems that [Michal Lonski](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49790674/5899172) has one, regarding that point.

Answer (score 1):

Probably the `System.lineSeparator()` was configured to be annotated with `@Deprecated` by mistake. You can position the text cursor on the method call and press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> and invoke `Deannotate @java.lang.Deprecated` to remove the annotation.

[image: The Deannoate @java.lang.Deprecated intention]

Answer (score 0):

You can use `String.format` and `%n`:

```
String output = String.format("Line one%nLine two");
```

The `%n` is a platform-independent newline character.

Comment: How does this answer the questions *why is this function deprecated? Is it a bad practice using line separators? What is the better way of doing this?*?

Comment: It is for the part *What is the better way of doing this?*

Comment: I would not call using `String.format` a better way of doing it though at all. You loose static type safety, performance wise you are shooting yourself in the leg and readability is also not decent.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `System.getProperty` with `line.separator` if your java version does not allow `System.lineSeparator()`.

```
final String LINE_SEPARATOR = System.getProperty("line.separator");
```